# How to calculate time in minutes between two dates in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch

How can I calculate time in minutes between two the dates in Sencha Touch ?

Exemple: I have two dates:

```
 entryStartTime=Thu Dec 07 2017 08:40:00 
 entryFinishTime=Thu Dec 07 2017 09:21:00
```

I want to get result : 41

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!!!

```
Ext.Date.diff( entryStartTime, entryFinishTime, Ext.Date.MINUTE )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) to calculate difference between dates with many options.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using single line JavaScript code.
Please try this,
var diffInMins= (entryFinishTime.getTime() - entryStartTime.getTime()) / 60000;